# WhenEvent with 2 conditions to stop integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I have this code that does not even work for a single condition, say

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2, y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3, 
   x[0] == 0.7, y[0] == 0.2, 
   WhenEvent[
    x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.2, {tMax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x, 
   y}, {t, 300}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0., 30.}]
```

and I want to go even further and include an additional condition like this

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2, y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3, 
   x[0] == 0.7, y[0] == 0.2, 
   WhenEvent[
    x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.7|| x[t]<1., {tMax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x, 
   y}, {t, 300}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the condition you wish to apply. You have  x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.7|| (*but need something here*)

Comment: Visually, it looks like your condition is never reached. {sx, sy} = 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2, y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3, 
   x[0] == 0.7, y[0] == 0.2, 
   WhenEvent[
    x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.7, {tMax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x, 
   y}, {t, 300}]; ParametricPlot[{sx[t], sy[t]}, {t, 0, 300}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.7]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

Comment: Hi, a side note: you should be able to get the value of `tMax` from `(x["Domain"] /. s)[[1,2]]` -- For your main question, I would advise using two separate `WhenEvent[]`. The event condition is subject to special interpretations that can be confusing. It's best to keep them simple. (`WhenEvent[A || B,...]` may be different that the two events separately; maybe you want one and not the other. I can't tell which you want from the question at present.)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I have edited the code following the suggestion by Craig Carter on the condition not being met and I have added the second condition. It still does not seem to stop where it should

Comment: As an event `x[t] < 1.` signifies `x[t]` crossing `x[t] == 1` while decreasing. Since `x[t] < 1.` is true throughout the integration, this event would never happen. The same holds for `x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.7` as an event. Finally, the event at hand, `x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.7 || x[t]<1.`, happens when the event changes from `False` to `True`, but again throughout the integration it is always `True`. So no event happens. As far as the code goes, `NDSolve` does exactly what it's supposed to do. What I don't understand is what it is that you want to have happen. Where should it stop?

Comment: I have finally "solved" it, WhenEvent does what it should, but ParametricPlot was the culprit for the wrong behaviour. Here is a working example with two conditions: s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2, y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3, 
   x[0] == 0.7, y[0] == 0.2, 
   WhenEvent[
    x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 < 0.2 || y[t] < 0, {tMax = t, 
     "StopIntegration"}]}, {x, y}, {t, 300}]